# Дополнительное вложение в tag

Tags: javascript

```js
            var a = 5;
            var b = 9;
            var result;
            

            document.writeln("<h3>Сумма<h3/>");
            result = a + b;
            document.write("<p>a + b = ", result, "</p>");
```

Почему второй write тоже вкладывается в h3?

Comment: `<h3/>` - не является закрывающим тегом. `"<h3>Сумма<h3/>"` -> `"<h3>Сумма</h3>"`

Comment: Потому что не правильно закрыт тег.

Answer (score 1):

`<h3/>` - не является закрывающим тегом.

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 9;
var result;


document.writeln("<h3>Сумма</h3>");
result = a + b;
document.write("<p>a + b = ", result, "</p>");
```